# Remove autogenerated straight route from Google Maps - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-layout, google-maps-api-2

I'm getting a straight line between my initial position and final position, which I don't want to show btw, along with the required route, like this:

[image]

How can I remove the straight line?

This is my code to draw the polyline:

```
setPolylines() async {
      Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("poly"),
        color: Colors.red[900],
        points: polylineCoordinates,
        width: 3,
      );

      _polylines.add(polyline);
  }
```

Thanks in advance..
(Please do let me know if I need to add more data to this question!)

Comment: Looks like that Polyline is a closed path.  Are you sure you're not missing an option somewhere?

Comment: idk to be honest. the one that's not straight, is the actual route. I manually provided the coordinates. the one that's straight, is not done by me and I've no idea how to get rid of it